# How do I keep Word from downloading templates over the company network?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

we have our templates stored on a central company server. Every time trying to open a document generated from a new template that I made, Word tries to download that template which is quite a slow process. If you're not logged into the network it is even slower. Nobody in the office knows what is happening or what to do.

I found a KB article that tells me to manipulate the registry (support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2763052) but that reads like a joke in a company network.

How can I change the document to work normally, without any downloading of any template and just working standalone? There's no external links in the document and I'm quite lost. Thanks a dozen.

Best
Benjamin

Comment: If anyone knows how to keep Word from repeating this behaviour with new documents that would be cool too.

Comment: Does your company IT have any group policies in place controlling Office (template locations, etc.)?  Is the template you made stored on the server or on your local computer?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for replying. Templates are stored locally on each employee computer and kept up-to-date via a distribution system made by our IT. This issue I'm seeing might be the reason for them doing that.

The template I made is on our department server - if I store it locally, the problem doesn't occur. Maybe it will be easiest if I just ask IT to include it in their distribution scheme.

Such an annoying issue for something that should be really straightforward!

Benjamin